# Include helpful terminology in answers

Tags: discussion, answers

Where appropriate, include terminology in answers that would allow you to do further research about a topic. For example, if I asked:

> I saw Australia represented in kanji with [豪州](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/531/on-the-replacing-of-kanji-obsoleted-in-the-1946-reforms-with-similar-looking-kanj). Is this derived from the Chinese characters given by admiral Zheng He's fleet when they discovered Australia?

Rather than just saying something like

> No, it's just a couple of kanji that sound like Gōshū.

try saying something like

> No, it's just a couple of kanji that sound like Gōshū. It's sometimes called 当て字{ateji}, which is either kanji used solely for its pronunciation but not its meaning or vice versa, or phonetic kanji.

Or, if someone's provided an answer, please add the terminology in a comment to the answer or the question.

Comment: 州 part is not ateji, although this is not the point of your question.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi feel free to edit my example.